# OctoPi command v412-ctl not found

Tags: octoprint

I try to set up the focus of my Logitech C920 in OctoPi. I follow several guides, which all propose to set the command `sudo v412-ctl --set-ctrl=focus_auto=0` by SSH'ing OctoPrint.
I always receive the answer in SSH, that `v412-ctl command not found`.
What's wrong?

Comment: It's an l (ell) not a 1 (one).

Answer (score 3):

It's an `l` (ell) not a `1` (one). `v4l2-ctl`.

Comment: well spotted! :-)